# Is there a way to flag/delete extremely offensive user names?

Tags: support

I don't want to see "modified 1 hour ago  [[extremely offensive username]](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/38973/niggerfaggot)".

Is there a way to eliminate this?

Right now people are seeing the N-word and an anti-gay slur when they go to the default Skeptics page.

[update: I edited the relevant question just so the "modified 1 hour ago ************" disappeared.]

Comment: The offensive answer lasted less than an hour before being deleted as offensive by the community. The account lasted about 2 hours before being mod-deleted as a spam/nonsense account. This question deserves a more general answer though.

Comment: @Oddthinking I think there should be a way to flag usernames, profiles, and bounty texts as offensive.

Comment: Yes, that's why I didn't post as an answer. Even if this one was handled quickly, what about the general case. I think it has been discussed before on Meta.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This general issue isn't specifically related to Skeptics.SE, so I went and did some spelunking on Meta.StackExchange to see how this had been handled in the past.

The general advice: [Flag one of their posts, and ask for moderator intervention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86621/how-should-i-flag-an-offensive-username).
[Another example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/flag-abusive-users)

If they [don't have a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128618/how-should-i-flag-a-user-account-if-it-has-no-posts-to-flag), flag anything. (If you are about to comment that this isn't a pretty solution, I agree!)

There's a ["semi-official" guideline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231334/is-it-acceptable-to-insult-god-in-a-user-profile/231338#231338) to how much leeway is allowed in posts, usernames and profiles. [Fake names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99914/what-are-the-rules-governing-display-names-and-avatars) are also discussed.

(As an Australian mod, I would point out there are large cultural differences between offensive terms. I'm not looking forward to being the arbiter on borderline cases. If it is blatantly obviously offensive, no problems, but if someone is sneaking in some dog-whistling or local term that we might not immediately recognise as offensive, help us out by explaining why you find it offensive.)

Comment: official policy image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7bPe.jpg

Comment: note to self: zardoz is allowed in profile